# laravel 9 visualization graph by group

Tags: laravel

I'm looking for a way to combine these two queries and create a visualization graph. Is there a way to do it and create a graph like this? This my code

Back

```
if (DB::table('esiti_audit')->where('employee', $name)->doesntExist()) {
    $dataaudit = "0";

    $areeaudit = "0";

} elseif (DB::table('esiti_audit')->where('employee', $name)->exists()) {

    $dataaudit = DB::table('esiti_audit')
        ->where('employee', $name)
        ->select('data_audit', 'esito')
        ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
        ->get();

    $areeaudit = DB::table('esiti_audit')
        ->where('employee', $name)
        ->select('master_zone', 'subarea', 'microarea')
        ->groupByRaw('master_zone, subarea, microarea')
        ->orderByDesc('data_audit')
        ->get();

};
```

result

I wish it came out like that

[image]

Comment: The graph you want to show is Audits that are dependent on areas. but `$dataaudit` doesnt have an area info. how will you show it on your graph ?

Comment: hi, in fact, I would like to find a way to extrapolate the data from the database based on the groups, showing the names of the areas only once and the various results